# python print out csv data based on date

Tags: python, csv

I have a python program that will print out the csv columns “expiration date” and “account name”. How would I write the code to only print out the account columns if the date in “expiration date” is only 3 days away from the time the code is executed?

Example of csv

expiration date   account name
1/2/2017            mary 4433
12/25/2018          bob 1244
1/31/2017           david 1234

code so far

```
import csv
with open('ResellerAccounts-1.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    accounts = []
    expiries = []
    for row in readCSV:
        account = row[0]
        expire = row[7]
        expiries.append(expire)
        accounts.append(account)
print(accounts)
print(expiries)
```

thanks!

Comment: please provide sample input and desired output

Answer (score 1):

You can add 3 days to the current day and then compare that value against expiry date in row[0] if they match the print the account

```
    import datetime
import csv
i = datetime.datetime.now()
end_date = i + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
end_date=end_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")


with open('ResellerAccounts-1.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(readCSV, None)  # skip the headers
    for row in readCSV:
        #compare the expiration date from row against current date + 3 
        if datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0],"%m/%d/%Y")==datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date,"%m/%d/%Y"):
            print row[2] # should print all rows matching the date 1/28/2017 for today's run
```

sample input

```
1/28/2017, mary, 4433 
12/25/2018, bob, 1244 
1/31/2017, david, 1234
```

output

```
  4433
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, what's the significance of 1/25/2015 in your example?

Comment: updated that value, its mean to hold the date of the code run

Comment: I tired running your example and it's printing out dates that are more than 3 days away?

Comment: can you add few inputs and outputs to the question?

Comment: maybe my code example was off. I need this to print out the column account name if the column expiration date happens to be 3 days away.

Comment: update the answer , now it will just print accounts for the expiry date in concern.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this and the numbers to write out to txt file. Thanks everyone for the help!

```
import datetime
import csv
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

#date, replace with the number gap you need
days=3
dt=(datetime.now() + timedelta(days)).strftime('%#m/%d/%Y')
text=open("call.txt","w")

with open("ResellerAccounts-1.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for r in reader:

        if r[7]==dt:
            #print the row mathing the date
            #print (r)
            t=r[0].split(" ")
            number=int(t[1])

            #print the number and the incremented number
            #print (t[1],number)
            text.write(str(number))
            text.write("\n")

print("Done..!!")
text.close()
```